# Append list according to their size in Java

Tags: java, list, arraylist, append, java-stream

I am trying to append two list according to their size. With list with bigger size in front.

I have few lists like this.

`List<Pair<Double, String>> masterList = new ArrayList<>();`

and this is the working Java code that I tried first - with a simple `if else` loop:

```
       if (listOne.size() >= listTwo.size()){
           masterList.addAll(listOne);
           masterList.addAll(listTwo);
       } else {
           masterList.addAll(listTwo);
           masterList.addAll(listOne);
       }
       masterList.addAll(otherList); // and at the end all other list can be added without any condition
```

I am fairly new to the Java, so I was studying about it and came across Comparators and Lambda. So, I tried to use that for my code, something like this:

```
List<Pair<Double, String>> masterList = Stream.concat(listOne.stream(), listTwo.stream())
                .filter(Comparator.comparingInt(List::size))
                .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

But I am not able to achieve proper results.
Can someone point out my mistake, I am still trying to learn.

Comment: Using streams seems quite unnecessary here, is there any reason you have to?

Comment: Mostly it was from a learning perspective. Also, with `Stream` the use case can be extended to more number of `List`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The for-loop is very nice, `Stream` isn't necessary, but to answer the question, you may

- not use `concat` as it'll already join the lists, and you loose the concept of different list
- don't use `filter` but rather `sorted`
- then `flatMap` to pass from `Stream<List<Pair<>>>` to `Stream<Pair<>>`

```
List<Pair<Double, String>> masterList = Stream.of(listOne, listTwo)
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(List::size, Comparator.reverseOrder()))
        .flatMap(List::stream)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
masterList.addAll(otherList);
```

Comment: @JoakimDanielson that is only the list the OP add at the end

Comment: also how about using 
`.sorted(Comparator.comparing(List::size, Comparator.reverseOrder()))`
sort them in reverse order and then flatten them - same thing different way

Comment: @PiyushAggarwal didn't remembered that construction, though about `.sorted(Comparator.comparing(List::size).reversed())` but error on `non static method cannot be referenced` and I didn't want to force a lmabda wuth specific type

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible to use `Stream.concat` to join the contents of `otherList` and thus to get rid of `masterList.addAll`

Also, there is an example of using `Comparator.reversed()` method:

```java
List<Pair<Double, String>> masterList = Stream.concat(
        Stream.of(listOne, listTwo) // Stream<List<Pair>>
          .sorted(Comparator.<List>comparingInt(List::size).reversed())
          .flatMap(List::stream), // Stream<Pair>
        otherList.stream() // Stream<Pair>
    )
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

---

However, a ternary operator should do fine as well to detect a longer list to place in the beginning:

```java
List<Pair<Double, String>> masterList2 = Stream.concat(
        (listOne.size() >= listTwo.size() 
            ? Stream.of(listOne, listTwo) 
            : Stream.of(listTwo, listOne)
        ) 
        .flatMap(List::stream),
        otherList.stream()
    )
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```